# C# WP8: How to call an async task method consecutively and get a new response every time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

This method:

```
 public async Task<string> GetjsonStream(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
```

Is called by this method:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String URL = URL_core + API_call;
        try
        {
            string response = await GetjsonStream(URL);
            JSONReturn answere = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONReturn>(response);
            output_box.Text = answere.value;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            output_box.Text = URL;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to have an API call happen every time a button is pressed on a page. I want to be able to keep pressing the button without re-loading the page and get a new result. However, right now I get the same response from the "GetjsonStream" method every time I press the button.

I am pretty sure I am mis-handling the async method. It seems like I need to either force a wait for it or initiate a fresh instance of the task. I am still new to C# and am learning as I go along, so I'm hoping there is just something obvious that I am missing.

EDIT: Some clarification:

The URL calls a random generator. So it should be a different result every time. 
When stepping through the "GetjsonStream" method, "content" will be the same every time.

Also, I found that if I wait for a minute or two, and press the button again, I do get a new result. I'm wondering if there is some timeout setting in place.

Comment: I am pretty sure your code does what you want it to do. Put a breakpoint in the `button_Click` and you will see that it goes inside whenever you click on it. Now, why should you get a different result every time? Isn't the target URL always the same? Also, there is a `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` ;)

Comment: I'll add an edit. The URL calls a random generator. So it should be a different result every time. 

When stepping through the "GetjsonStream" method, "content" will be the same every time.

Comment: Try appending `"?=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks` at the end of your url, it is possible that the response is cached since the URL is the same between requests. If you refresh that page in your browser, do you get a new response on each try?

Comment: Yes, I can keep re-submitting the URL in a browser and it generates a new response every time. It basically just takes some boundaries and just generates random chars based on how many are needed. So I can pass the same input every time and get different values each time. 

If I change the value in "API_Call" it does return a new response. So I think caching might be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am pretty sure I am mis-handling the async method.

No, but you are mishandling HTTP. :)

HTTP gets can be cached. Since the API should always return a different result, the server should be modified to send headers disabling caching.

Comment: I added this: 

`header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');`

`header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);`

`header('Pragma: no-cache');`


to the PHP file that does the json encoding and it works like a charm now. 

Thank You!